# What distribution does Java's Random follow?

Tags: java

What distribution does Java's [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) follow?

Comment: It says pretty clearly in the description for each function. Which part are you unclear about? (uniform for all except `nextGaussian()`)

Comment: @Mysticial, Sorry, I missed that part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Random Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) says it's a uniform distribution. If you use [`nextGaussian()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian%28%29), you get a [Gaussian distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) double value.